# dotenv varibles are not loading in new Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby version `2.1.6p336`

Rails version `4.2.1`

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
gem 'zendesk_api', '~> 1.13.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

config/.env:

```
ZD_EMAIL=         "hermes@olympus.com"
ZD_API_TOKEN=     "ἙρμῆςκριοφόροςἈργειφόντης"
ZD_DOMAIN=        "olympus.zendesk.com"
```

config/application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module ZendeskSupportPortal
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

I'm not trying to load them for a production environment, I'm trying to load them the standard way, just for development. But when I start the rails console and check, for example, `ENV['ZD_EMAIL']`, it returns nil.

I've tried everything mentioned in these two issues (in dotenv repo):

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/issues/144

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/issues/191

This is my first time using dotenv. Although the installation instructions are simple, I must be making a rookie mistake. Please enlighten me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a rookie mistake. I should have put the `.env` file in the root directory instead of `config/.env`. Putting it in the root directory (per the installation instructions) solved the issue.